# How do you draw text shadow for SwiftUI's `Text` view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

With something like `Text("Hello, World!")`, how can I apply a soft dark text-shadow to it?

Comment: Is `.shadow(radius: 5)` what you are looking for?

Comment: That doesn't add shadow to the text. Add `.shadow(radius: 5)` to a `Text` view creates a box around the view with that shadow. Is there a way to clip that shadow to the shape of the text?

Comment: @garrettmaring can you show some more code? The order of the modifiers are important

Comment: Actually, yep it is clipping to the text with the accepted answer!  The box appearance came from the shadow abruptly ending when the containing view clipped it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: Hello, World! with soft black shadow underneath]

```
Text("Hello, World!")
    .font(.system(size: 30))
    .shadow(
        color: Color.primary.opacity(0.3), /// shadow color
        radius: 3, /// shadow radius
        x: 0, /// x offset
        y: 2 /// y offset
    )
```

Comment: Had better results with just `color: Color.gray`.